# Appengine: Routing to a different appspot.com

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a app 
**abc.appspot.com**

Now, I want a url **abc.appspot.com/blog**.  This url should serve from **abcblog.appspot.com**.  I don't want a redirect.

Is this possible with dispatch.yaml

Basically, I want to introduce a blog in my app, but from a different appspot.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default routing by routing via URL or you can use routing with a dispatch file.

For your case I think creating a dispatch file will be the suitable way to do what you want since it will override the App Engine's routing rules and you can define your own custom routing rules.

To create a dispatch file you should put it in your root directory of your default service and you can define up to 20 routing rules in the dispatch file.

An example from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#routing_with_a_dispatch_file):

```
dispatch:
  # Send all mobile traffic to the mobile frontend.
  - url: "*/mobile/*"
    service: mobile-frontend

  # Send all work to the one static backend.
  - url: "*/work/*"
    service: static-backend
```

You can check this to see [how to properly configure your dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml).

Comment: In the dispatch file, I am concerned wheather 'service' will accept a different appspot.com.  am I right?

Comment: It will accept different service but from the same appspot.com/. @sneascu shared the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml#module) you can find here some extra examples.